# Stateless Session Beans Object Identity

Tags: ejb-3.1, java-ee-7

The Specifications for EJB 3.2 Section 3.4.7.2 Stateless Session Beans show following code to demonstrate equality:

```
@EJB Cart cart1;
@EJB Cart cart2;
...
if (cart1.equals(cart1)) { // this test must return true
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not obvious, we are infact talking about references to proxies managed by the container.

However the example is mostly used toghether with the `Stateful` bean where the same equals instruction return `false`. The container in that case returns a new reference, and you end up with two distinct beans.

**UPDATE**

Uhm...I made a mistake, as I have read `cart1.equals(cart2)`. In such case, I have to say that it is almost obvious as you have noticed.

However, just because it is not a simple reference that you have obtained with `new`, but it is something that the app server is managing for you, it is good to know that it is serving you the same object identity. This especially true and fundamental in the case of a `Stateful`.

Right now I cannot think of any useful purpose for a `Stateless` bean for having the same object identity compared to a `Stateful` but I am sure that there are some examples.

Comment: actually according to the specifications in section 3.4.7.1 `Stateful` session beans the statement `cart1.equals(cart1)` must - also - return `true`